# Why does ApiController return empty Dictionary when the value type is nullable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-apicontroller

Consider this controller:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class ExampleController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public Dictionary<string, int?> Get()
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, int?>()
            {
                {"foo", null},
                {"bar", 1}
            }; 
        }
    }
}
```

When I access this controller through `/example`, I get a response containing only `{}`. No errors or warnings in the console.

However, if I remove the `?` sign after `int` (i.e. changing nullable integer to not nullable) and replace `null` with `0`, it returns the Dictionary as it should. The issue happens with `decimal`, `bool` and `char`, too.

It should be noted that not all nullable types behave that way. For example, `string` works just fine.

Edited controller:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class ExampleController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public Dictionary<string, int> Get()
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, int>()
            {
                {"foo", 0},
                {"bar", 1}
            }; 
        }
    }
}
```

Response:

```
{"foo":0,"bar":1}
```

Return types like `int?` and `List<int?>` work as expected, only the Dictionary has issues.

**Why is this happening? Who is to blame?**

I'm using `.NET Core SDK (3.0.100)`, target framework is `netcoreapp3.0`. I created this WebApplication using JetBrains Rider's GUI (`File` -> `New...` -> `ASP.NET Core Web Application` -> Type: `Web API`).

Comment: It most likely depends on the underlying JSON framework. Try figuring which one is used (probably Newtonsoft.JSON), and then try using it directly to see how it would serialize the same data. Then we'll see.

Comment: I tried this in .net core 3 and it indeed behaves like that, in .net core 2.2 it works as expected.

Comment: This is most likely a bug in new JSON serializer that I've encountered. Try using Newtonsoft serializer instead :

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/40991

Comment: Check thread https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/40120

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code in ASP.Net Core 2.2 and it worked leading me to believe that this is an issue with new Microsoft's JSON serializer which is supposed to replace the Newtonsoft one used previously.

I managed fix this issue by installing the old Newtonsoft one:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson -Version 3.0.0
```

And using it as such:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson();
}
```

Just add the `AddNewtonsoftJson` to your configuration. The method allows you to setup JSON serializer as you normally would, although I haven't tinkered with that.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'll write an answer for other people who may encounter the same issue:

There is a well-known bug in a new built-in JSON serializer that comes with Asp.Net Core 3.0. It has difficulties serializing nullable values. Not only nullables in dictionaries but in nested objects orwhen it has to do string -> nullable conversion. It was designed in a way that allows to significantly improve performance but apparently it is still in a 'row' state.

So it is better for now to use Newtonsoft serializer:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

services.AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
    options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
});
```

As Oliver kindly pointed out there is a bug opened for this [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/40991)